# Is it possible to automatically assign an email address using php?

Tags: php, email, automation

After registering on my site I can make people moderators which just changes 1 value in my database. Whilst doing this would it be possible to create a forwarded email address using my domain name to their current email address? I would use their username @mydomain.com. I use the hosting service ipage.

Is this in any way possible or would I have to do this manually?

Comment: This depends on your email service and has little to do with php.

Comment: I understand that but I was wondering how I could intergrate them

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating email address via PHP or any other script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933811/creating-email-address-via-php-or-any-other-script)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933811/creating-email-address-via-php-or-any-other-script/5091785#5091785

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emails setups can be (and usually are) very different from server to server. Some have email right on the same box as the website while others have separate, dedicated email servers. However, most do not allow a programmatic way to create boxes or forwards (rather, they can only be done through some sort of control panel). You will need to contact iPage support to ask them if there is a pertinent, alternate way to create them.